# Semantic problem with index and position in lists of python

Tags: python, list, indexing, position

why in a quiz on Python lists is the code for inserting a value (5) in the third position of the list this one ?

```
list1 = [11, 2, 23]
list1.insert(3,5)
print(list1)
```

Shouldn't it be list1.insert(2,5) since , even if the index in a list start at 0 ,the third position is,imho,  index 2 ?
Sorry for the maybe trivial question ( I'm a newbie) but I thought that when you ask for the third position in a list you don't refer to index 3 but to the item that is in the third place starting from left.

I tried to use different values in .insert() but , as expected, this didn't solve my doubt

Comment: The quiz is using zero-based indexing when it writes "third position".

Comment: From the docs: "The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert"

Comment: @001 The OP understands that. Their confusion is because the quiz says "third position", which they intepret as meaning index=2.

Comment: What you're seeing is that English can be ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for your comments: the refernce to the docs si quite clear and I must admit that I hadn't read the "official" docs. Thanks for your help and patience in helping a newbie

Comment: There's no rule. Some people will start counting at zeroth, so you don't have to adjust when converting to list indexes. Some will start at first, so you have to subtract 1.

Comment: The quiz author starts at zeroth.

Comment: I see. I guess your instructor should be more specific. To me, "Position" is ambiguous. "Index" is specific.

Comment: The last comment on "ambiguity" is  imho absolutely correct: for a newbie coding is already difficult and ambiguity just increases difficulty

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Python shell help command:

```
>>> help(list1.insert)

insert(index, object, /) method of builtins.list instance
    Insert object before index.
```

It inserts before the index, not after. If you try `2`, it's after index 1 but before the existing index 2, giving you a new index 2. If you try `3`, it's after 2 and before 3. But since there isn't a 3, it's just put on the end of the list.

And it all makes sense. As long as you are within the current bounds of the list, "index" is what the index will be after insertion.

Using the shell, you can see it all in action

```
>>> list1 = [11, 2, 23]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for i, val in enumerate(list1):
...     print(f"{i}: {val}")
... 
0: 11
1: 2
2: 23
>>> 
>>> list1.insert(3,5)
>>> 
>>> for i, val in enumerate(list1):
...     print(f"{i}: {val}")
... 
0: 11
1: 2
2: 23
3: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The position in a list in python is the same as the index. Or more formally:
each element inside a list will have a unique position that identifies it. That position is called the element's index.

Because if you run the code you will get the following list:

```
[11, 2, 23, 5]
```

Here is also a definition of the insert function, with parameters:

insert() Parameters
The insert() method takes two parameters:

index - the index where the element needs to be inserted
element - this is the element to be inserted in the list